# How do you inject this code into HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="bar" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width: 0%; height: 10px; background-color:#e81d61;"></div>
```

I am developing a chrome plugin but am facing an issue. So, I need to inject this code into the body and manipulate the style in JavaScript; all this to be done in JavaScript by the way. Please help :)

What I have tried:

```
var div = document.createElement("div").id="bar";
div.bar.style.position = "fixed";
div.bar.style.top = "0";
div.bar.style.left = "0";
div.bar.style.height = "10px";


document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem with appending that HTML snippet to the body of a webpage? What have you tried? What was the error message you got or the problem you had with your approach?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Assign the `id` separately. `document.createElement("div").id="bar"` returns the string "bar"

Comment: @ThumChoonTat tried that too ```div.id = "bar";``` didnt work

Comment: `var.div` and `div.bar` don't mean anything here. Just use `div`.

Comment: @MrLister I'm a beginner, sorry. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you think `div.bar` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("id", "bar");
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.top = "0";
div.style.left = "0";
div.style.height = "50px";
div.style.width = "50px";
div.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```